# Assign UI element to a property in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to assign a UI element to a property using XAML

I have build my Dependency Property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "Owner",
    typeof(Panel),
    typeof(Clock),
    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
);

public Panel Owner
{
    get => owner;
    set
    {
        owner = value;
        ...
     }
 }
```

And my XAML code:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid"/>
<Page.Resources>
    <local:Clock x:Key="Clock"  Owner="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

When launching my program I get an exception. Unfortunately the debugger doesn't tell me which.

So in short: How do I bind a UI control to property using XAML?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the bug myself:

First make sure your class inherits from `DependencyObject`

Next make a OnchangeEvent on your `DependencyProperty`

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        nameof(Owner),
        typeof(Panel),
        typeof(Clock),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OwnerChanged)
    );
```

Last but not least implement `OwnerChanged`:

```
private static void OwnerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Clock)d).Owner = e.NewValue as Panel;
}
```

Comment: If you had implemented the dependency property correctly in the first place, by using `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` as the sole statements in the property getter and setter, respectively, you wouldn't have to do this at all. It would've just worked.

Comment: @PeterDuniho an example would be most welcome.Remember that my setter isn't just a simple setter.

Comment: _"an example would be most welcome"_ -- did you look in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-register-an-attached-property)? That's usually a good place to start. _"my setter isn't just a simple setter"_ -- well, it has to be, if you want it to be correct. You can't put anything else in there, because dependency properties don't use your own setter or getter for binding operations.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sofar you have only told me to look in the documentation, which I've already did. But I need to have my own setter, so I can't see GetValue and SetValue as an solution. That's why I'd ask for an example. Without using an Onchange Event.

Comment: _"I need to have my own setter"_ -- no, you don't, and you can't. Whatever it is that makes you think you do, you're wrong, and you ought to be asking a question about _that_ instead of trying to get the incorrect implementation to work. Your "work-around" above solves one problem while creating another. (That said, in my earlier comment I referred you to the attached property documentation, when you should look here instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register?view=netframework-4.7.1)